# Receiving 404s in my React app despite setting historyApiFallback to true for webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I'm developing a React application, which is currently served at http://localhost:3000/, and I was hoping to get some basic routing working on it. I've been loosely following [the Redux guide](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/UsageWithReactRouter.html#componentsrootjs) however I can't seem to set up a fallback URL correctly. After applying the webpack changes described in the guide, accessing any link such as http://localhost:3000/test results in a 404 response and the "Cannot GET /test" error. The index.jsx file which defines the route looks as follows:

**index.jsx**

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import App from './components/App';
import rootReducer from './reducers/';

/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
/* eslint-enable */

const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
));

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/(:filter)" component={App} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Within the webpack config I've tried using `historyApiFallback: true` as well as `historyApiFallback: { index: 'index.html' }` and a few variations for the value of the index property. This is the full configuration:

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  debug: true,
  devtool: '#eval-source-map',
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve('./src'),
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: '/',
    },
  },
  entry: [
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './index',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'] },
    ],
  },
};
```

Any ideas for what might be going wrong?

Edit: There's also some BrowserSync configuration which *may* be related:

**app.js**

```
/**
 * Require Browsersync along with webpack and middleware for it
 */
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
var webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');

/**
 * Require ./webpack.config.js and make a bundler from it
 */
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
var bundler = webpack(webpackConfig);

/**
 * Run Browsersync and use middleware for Hot Module Replacement
 */
browserSync({
  server: {
    baseDir: 'src',

    middleware: [
      webpackDevMiddleware(bundler, {
        // IMPORTANT: dev middleware can't access config, so we should
        // provide publicPath by ourselves
        publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,

        // pretty colored output
        stats: { colors: true },

        // for other settings see
        // http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-middleware.html
      }),

      // bundler should be the same as above
      webpackHotMiddleware(bundler),
    ],
  },

  // no need to watch '*.js' here, webpack will take care of it for us,
  // including full page reloads if HMR won't work
  files: [
    'src/css/*.css',
    'src/*.html',
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `browserHistory`, you must configure your `server` appropriately to serve at all `routed` paths:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.0.0-rc5/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#configuring-your-server

But if you don't want to put express server additionally just to make hot reloading work, use this:

```
webpack-dev-server -d --history-api-fallback --hot --inline --progress --colors
```

Comment: Isn't that what the historyApiFallback setting seeks to achieve?

https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#the-historyapifallback-option

The only difference I see between what I'm trying and the suggested fix, is that I'm making the change in the webpack.config.js file whereas the fix uses the command line option.

Comment: ya i think they are same.

Answer (score 0):

Though I was unable to get browserHistory working in my local dev environment, switching to hashHistory is a good enough fix for the short-term.